# Windows 2008 Task Scheduler - Other User unable to run the Task

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, scheduled-tasks

I have created a scheduled Task in Windows 2008 Task Scheduler. (as a member of the local admin group). It runs on time and I can run the task anytime I want. 
However if a coworker tries to run the same task he can't because insufficent permissions, but he is also member of the local admin group).
Anybody having an idea what is wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the event viewer under windows logs > Application and Security logs for errors.  If there are none (I'd be surprised) then run the application through the debugger with the problem account, easy way is to login as him.  You can go into visual studio menu > Debug > Exceptions > Common Language Runtime > Checkoff "Thrown" and start the application.  This will make it stop when any error is thrown even if its handled.  That should pinpoint any access problems.

Comment: The funny thing is, if my coworker creates an new task in the scheduler I can't even see this scheduled task.

Comment: Are you on a domain?  Domain permissions override local permissions.

Comment: Yes of course we run the stuff within a domain. It is just weird to see that the behavior between 2003 and 2008 is so different. Or should I say the interface got worse ? Is there a way to see what policies/permissions got applied from the domain and might overwrite local stuff ?

Comment: I'm not too good with policies and stuff.  My gut says to look into gpedit.msc, but your better off asking that kind of question on serverfault.com.  If its just a difference between 2003 and 2008 then UAC may have something to do with it.  Again, I'd ask on serverfault.com.